# clojure same ":or" value for all keys

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I've defined a record with a bunch of fields--some of which are computed, some of which don't map directly to keys in the JSON data I'm ingesting. I'm writing a factory function for it, but I want to have sensible default/not-found values. Is there a better way that tacking on `:or [field1 "" field2 "" field3 "" field4 ""...]`? I could write a macro but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Comment: Why would `:or {...}` not be good enough? What qualifies something as better than that?

Comment: A `merge` might be more explicit than using `:or` in destructuring, and `rename-keys` might help with the different key names, but it's difficult to say without seeing the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three common idioms for implementing defaults in constructor functions.

1. `:or` destructoring

   Example:

   ```
   (defn make-creature [{:keys [type name], :or {type :human
                                                 name (str "unnamed-" (name type))}}]
     ;; ...
     )
   ```

   This is useful when you want to specify the defaults inline.  As a bonus, it allows `let` style bindings in the `:or` map where the kvs are ordered according to the `:keys` vector.
2. Merging

   Example:

   ```
   (def default-creature-spec {:type :human})

   (defn make-creature [spec]
      (let [spec (merge default-creature-spec
                        spec)]
         ;; ....
         ))
   ```

   This is useful when you want to define the defaults externally, generate them at runtime and/or reuse them elsewhere.
3. Simple `or`

   Example:

   ```
   (defn make-creature [{:keys [type name]}]
     (let [type (or type :human)
           name (or name (str "unnamed-" (name type)))]
        ;; ...
        ))
   ```

   This is as useful as `:or` destructoring but only those defaults are evaluated that are actually needed, i. e. it should be used in cases where computing the default adds unwanted overhead. (I don't know why `:or` evaluates all defaults (as of Clojure 1.7), so this is a workaround).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the same default value for all the fields, and they really have to be different than `nil`, and you don't want to write them down again, then you can get the record fields by calling `keys` on an empty instance, and then construct a map with the default values merged with the actual values:

```
(defrecord MyFancyRecord [a b c d])

(def my-fancy-record-fields (keys (map->MyFancyRecord {})))
;=> (:a :b :c :d)

(def default-fancy-fields (zipmap my-fancy-record-fields (repeat "")))

(defn make-fancy-record [fields]
  (map->MyFancyRecord (merge default-fancy-fields
                             fields)))

(make-fancy-record {})
;=> {:a "", :b "", :c "", :d ""}

(make-fancy-record {:a 1})
;=> {:a 1, :b "", :c "", :d ""}
```

To get the list of record fields you could also use the static method `getBasis` on your record class:

```
(def my-fancy-record-fields (map keyword (MyFancyRecord/getBasis)))
```

(`getBasis` is not part of the public records api so there are no guarantees it won't be removed in future clojure versions. Right now it's available in both clojure and [clojurescript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/d33b6d09da6ff2ed91da0ab8222e52ca9fdf1c91), it's usage is explained in "Clojure programming by Chas Emerick, Brian Carper, Christophe Grand" and it's also mentioned [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/1jDRPI0Bbs8) during a discussion about how to get the keys from a record. So, it's up to you to decide if it's a good idea to use it)